# JSF displaying different item on another page depending on ID, JSF 2.2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Im trying to get an ID from one page to another when a button is clicked depending on what button i click i will get different ids, and from that i want to display info from a list with the id as Index. The problem is that i get an error when using dispatch and this is the error:

> Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
>   NullPointerException.

When souting the IDs i get the one i want but this is before i'm redirected/dispatched to the other page. In the Product page i always get the first object of the list

I don't get any error when using Redirect but still i only get the first object in the list

Is the page already initialized? How do i work around that if that is the case.

Im using JSF 2.2 and is using Dependent scope on the snowboardBean

SnowboardBean

```
public void saveId(){
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String tempID = params.get("id");

                id = Integer.parseInt(tempID) - 1;

        System.out.println("ForwardID");
        System.out.println(getId());

        try {
            fc.getExternalContext().dispatch("infopage.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SnowboardBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

index.html here save ID is called

```
<h:dataTable value="#{snowboardBean.snowList}" var="list">
                <h:column>
                    <h:form>

                    ID: #{list.id}<br></br>
                    Product Name: #{list.productName}<br></br>
                    Brand Name: #{list.brandName} <br></br>

                        <h:commandLink action="#{snowboardBean.forwardId()}" value="insert">
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{list.id}" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:form>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

Displaying it, Product.xhtml:

```
CURRENT ID: #{snowboardBean.id}
        <ui:param name="id" value="#{snowboardBean.id}"/>
        <h:dataTable value="#{snowboardBean.snowList[id]}" var="list">
            <h:column>
                ID: #{list.id}<br></br>
                Product Name: #{list.productName}<br></br>
                Brand Name: #{list.brandName} <br></br>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

The output i get when clicking on the first button is:

> ForwardID
>   0

and if i click on the second button i get:

> ForwardID
>   1

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Added additonal information about the scope, jsf version, where my method is called from and what outputs i get.

Edit 2: Clarified

Comment: It would be nice if you could share the JSF version as well as the `snowboardBean` scope ... More data you share more chances you will get correct answer :) Also the output of the system.outs :) How the `saveId()` is called

Comment: Noted @Babl, ill begin to do that! Thanks for the help.

Using JSF 2.2 and snowboardBean is using dependent scope